# Fitting images of varying sizes into div elements

Tags: html, css

We are generating player images inside of circles, as such:

```css
div.intable-player-image {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 1px auto;
    max-height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 150px; ">
  <div class="intable-player-image" style="pointer-events: auto;">
    <a class="logo" href="/">
      <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cbb-image-files/PlayerHeadshots/105304-965025.png" alt="player-face" style="width: 100%;/* height: 100%; */">
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="intable-player-image" style="pointer-events: auto;">
    <a class="logo" href="/">
      <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cbb-image-files/PlayerHeadshots/105676-963793.png" alt="player-face" style="width: 100%;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="intable-player-image" style="pointer-events: auto;">
    <a class="logo" href="/">
      <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cbb-image-files/PlayerHeadshots/104923-1321451.png" alt="player-face" style="width: 100%;">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The player images are all shapes and sizes. Some images have a greater width than height (first image), others have a greater height than width (2nd, 3rd image). Our goal is to display these as nicely-sized as possible with a one-size-fits-all approach.

In the example above, the 1st image is the main problem due to the white space showing. Any recommendations on how we can tweak the styles to improve the fit of the first image, without messing up the 2nd and 3rd images? As a bonus, having the player's face in the 2nd image appear slightly larger would be an improvement to the current solution as well.

Comment: Are you here for a ready solution? Or you will share what have you tied, where it went wrong, and what s the exact error you have issues with? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I don't think you can expect the images to have different ratios, fill the same size containers, and look good at the same time. Something has to give imo, or you need to get creative with the background/other elements in the page to make the disproportion appear seamless

Comment: JavaScript can look at the dimensions of an image and give the smallest side `100%` and the other side `auto`. Also you have to vertical and horizontal  center 
 the image in the div container (for example using flexbox).

Answer (score 1):

`object-fit` and `object-position` are used to control the positioning and scaling elements within their container.

The `object-fit` property specifies how the image should be resized to fit its container, while preserving its aspect ratio.

The `object-position` property defines the positioning of the image within its container.

```css
div.intable-player-image {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 1px auto;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
}

div.intable-player-image img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 500px; ">
  <div class="intable-player-image" style="pointer-events: auto;">

      <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cbb-image-files/PlayerHeadshots/105304-965025.png" alt="player-face" style="width: 100%;/* height: 100%; */">

  </div>
  <div class="intable-player-image" style="pointer-events: auto;">
    <a class="logo" href="/">
      <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cbb-image-files/PlayerHeadshots/105676-963793.png" alt="player-face" style="width: 100%;">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="intable-player-image" style="pointer-events: auto;">
    <a class="logo" href="/">
      <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cbb-image-files/PlayerHeadshots/104923-1321451.png" alt="player-face" style="width: 100%;">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the example, `object-fit: cover;` is used to set the image to cover the entire container, while maintaining its aspect ratio. This means that the image will be scaled to fill the container while cropping any excess from either the width or height to fit perfectly inside the container div.

`object-position: center 10%;` is used to set the image to center horizontally and 10% from the top of the container. This means that the image will be centered horizontally and the top 10% of the image will be cropped.

Together, these properties ensure that the images are scaled to fit their container divs while preserving their aspect ratios and maintaining the desired positioning.

Comment: I don’t fully understand where the 10% came from. How do we know that is right for all possible aspect ratios/actual face positions?

Comment: It's just a guess based on experience

Comment: But you are using object-fit cover.

Comment: I think this is the best answer because a face is usually in the center or top half of an image. As far as I know, css can't parse a photo to recognize a face **:-))**

Comment: This looks very good. We understand that not every image is going to look perfect within the circle, but this is quite good.

Comment: @MarcBarbeau - there is something about the outer div with `width: 500` that is forcing this to work. Remove that outer div, and the first image is problematic again. That outer wrapper div shouldn't matter at all to how these look though?

Comment: and shrinking the images from 150px to 26px causes its own issues as well

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image nested in a div element all you need to do is set the max-width of the image to 100% it will be confined to the size of the div.

```html
<div>
  <img src="your-source" alt="dont-forget-good-alternative-text">
</div>
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

In the example above, the images max width would be dictated by the parent div, and wouldn't grow larger than 100px.